# What does binding mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am reading about monomorphism restriction und it exists to binding.

1. function binding
2. pattern binding

But I would like to know, what does binding mean in Haskell?

For example, is this a value binding?

```
n = 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Binding* in Haskell means the same thing as it does in other functional languages: Lisp, Scheme, ML, ... . It binds a value to a name (or, a name to a value).

So, yes, in `let { n = 10 } in n + n`, `n = 10` is a binding.

Related concept is *scope*. Another is *closure*. Absent mutation as it is, both are simpler, in Haskell, than in non-pure languages (like Lisp, ML, etc.).

Comment: Could you please give a simpler explanation about `Related concept is scope. Another is closure`. What do you exactly mean?

Comment: scope is a related, but separate concept.  maybe it is better to ask a separate question.

Comment: But how should I ask the question. Because I am not confidence with the topic

Comment: well, a scope (of a name / variable) is a region of code where that name's binding is visible; is a short answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your help.

Comment: So all regions in code where you could legally use that name to refer to its value (its binding) is that name's scope. You're welcome. :)